# How to get the ID of the current Contact with PHP Mautic API?

Tags: php, mautic

As I couldn't find anything in the documentation I might have a general understanding issue. But what I want to achieve is getting the ID of the current Contact browsing the Site. To get user details I always have to know the ID, like documented here: https://developer.mautic.org/#contacts

```
$api        = new MauticApi();
$contactApi = $api->newApi("contacts", $auth, $settings['baseUrl']);
$contact    = $contactApi->get(3);
```

Is there a way to the ID of the current Contact? I want to play highly customized content on the website and an entry point to get user details.

Comment: There's a little more information needed from you, at some point you must have gotten the "current contact" information, via a login or something similar, doesn't that information contain the id or even the complete contact object?

Comment: Hi. It's not about Mautic User. It's about the tracked contact on the website. When a user visits the site, he's tracked as contact and get's an ID. I want to know how I can get that ID and use it with the API so I can select more information to work with.

Comment: If i understand it right, you are talking about the time when contact has already been created and is visiting the page again(through email campaign or otherwise) if the cookie is set you want to show different or customized content ?
For this you can use dynamic content but that works on mautic's own landing page not sure if it works on wp or other places, Try to check if the cookie in your browser matches the contact id that can be one way to obtain the ID. you can try out with a test contact at your end.

Answer (score 0):

It's a REST API, so you should get a response in any case. What's the content of the response (eg. what contains `$contact`)? What's the HTTP code of the response? Error messages?

However... I'm not familiar with this particular API, but the principles are always the same

https://developer.mautic.org/?php#list-contacts

Without any query parameters it should give the full list of contacts. Each of the contact records should come with an ID for the details:

https://developer.mautic.org/?php#get-contact

As said, I'm not familiar with the API, so it could be that you get a contact list only from a higher entity, like a Company or so.

I can recommend Postman (https://www.postman.com/), a neat tool to make REST API requests while having full control over all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to get the details of the current logged in user.

You can use the`mautic.helper.user` helper to do that as shown below:

```
<?php
$user = $this->get('mautic.helper.user')->getUser();

$firstName = $user->getFirstname();
$lastName  = $user->getLastname();
$email     = $user->getEmail();
$profile   = $user->getProfile();

$role = $user->getRole()->getName();

if ($role->isAdmin()) {
    // do something
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mautic.org/#services44

Comment: I want to get the ID of the contact currently browsing the website. So like: "Hello Mr. Smith, nice to have you here."

Comment: @lufi will the contact browsing the site log into the site?

Comment: No, that's not how mautic work. Per Mautic definition: "The next time the tracking script sends a request to Mautic, it will use the device ID from the browser's local storage to identify the tracked Contact. If that cannot be found, Mautic will default to the cookies stored on it's own domain (so third party cookies) to identify the Contact." - So the contact is identified by mautic and internally gets a unique id. To request informations through the API the ID is needed. "$contactApi->get(3);" for example. I would like to know to get the ID of the current contact in the PHP API.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want here I do not think you actually need the API to get the user id.  Mautic has dynamic content and as long as the user has a cookie dropped on his browser you can use Dynamic Content to say "Hi {contactfield=firstname}, welcome back.

You can actually call any custom field into the dynamic content slot.

Check out dynamic content which is found under the Components section in the left menu